# presentViewController shows black sceen while UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal objective c

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, ios9.1, uimodaltransitionstyle, rootviewcontroller

I'm facing issue with the UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal, Which gives black screen at background while transition and shows the actual screen.

[image]

After first time it shows the last view which added as rootview.

[image]

What actually I need to achieve is I don want to show the black and previous screen. It should show an empty screen background as like the below image.

[image]

The code I used to achieve the transition is

```
- (void)popViewController {
    UIViewController* rootController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainViewController"];

    rootController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:rootController];

    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:navigation animated:YES completion:nil];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

I'm using storyboard with dynamic rootview.Anybody help me to fix it out.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove subview

Add this code on your method `popViewController`

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate =(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
NSArray *subViewArray = [appDelegate.window subviews];
for (id obj in subViewArray)
          {
            [obj removeFromSuperview];
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by add window subview with background.

```
UIImageView* background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height)];
background.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TermsBg"];
[self.window addSubview:background];
```